# How to have a canvas wave divider but vertically?

Tags: html

I'm using this generator [https://getwaves.io](https://getwaves.io/) to get wave divider, but I'm looking for a way to have it vertically, I've use `transform: rotate(45deg);` but it doesn't work as the width becomes the height, and vice versa.

Here's the code of the SVG :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
<path fill="#fff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,256L60,261.3C120,267,240,277,360,250.7C480,224,600,160,720,160C840,160,960,224,1080,250.7C1200,277,1320,267,1380,261.3L1440,256L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z">
</path>
</svg>
```

I've hope you'll be able to help me :)